# Who keeps upvoting these terrible questions?

Tags: discussion, voting, statistics

> Who keeps up-voting terrible lazy questions, questions that show absolutely no evidence of effort? Please stop doing this. – [Hovercraft Full Of Eels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/522444/hovercraft-full-of-eels) [17 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44209922/code-for-the-twelve-game-chase#comment75432368_44209922)
>   <sub>[(Screenshot for <10K)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaRWB.png)</sub>

Many times I have felt the same way. I come across some mess of a question with no formatting, no punctuation and no effort shown whatsoever, and sure enough there's an upvote on it. It takes a lot of self-control to not go on an all-caps rant about who on earth upvotes these questions.

But I'm here to ask exactly that:

## Who actually upvotes these questions?

Before you burn me alive, I'm not looking for names - I'm looking for statistics.

What really interests me is *why* they get upvoted, but I'd wager you don't have that data. The next best thing is *who* casts the upvotes, which I hope will provide some indication as to *why*.

All reasons I can think of don't sound particularly convincing:

- People are stupid enough to actually find such questions good
- Sock puppetry (IMO unlikely if the main account has only 1 rep)
- Some misguided attempt at encouragement...?
- Mis-clicks, blind upvoting spree, ...?

---

Now, I'm looking for some data on upvotes on "terrible" questions. Let's 
first define a "terrible" question as (matching **all of** the following):

- Having either a score of -3 or less, or being closed as "unclear"
- Having no more than 5 upvotes

For all users who have cast upvotes on such questions, could we please get some graphs or data dumps on (the distribution of):

- Whether the account still exists (if you even retain such info for deleted accounts)
- Their reputation
- Their upvotes-to-downvotes ratio
- The age of their account at the time the vote was cast
- The amount of votes cast on terrible questions by the same person (i.e. is it always the same bunch of people, or do most of them just cast 1 such vote?)

I'm also inclined to ask for the geographical location of such users, but... I feel like that might break the anonymity that votes should have.

Would be awesome if someone could provide that data. :)

Comment: Voting rings, or similar fraud.

Comment: I would guess sympathy upvoters, particularly from those users who have found themselves in similar situations and think it's "unfair" for a question to have so many (unexplained) downvotes. Also users who are gaming for the voting badges ← huge one.

Comment: There are really 'sympathy upvoters'?  I thought they were a cyber-myth:)  I never got any on my bad questions!

Comment: If such bad/low quality questions have answers, some users who posted answers to the question will just upvote them in hope to save the question, so they can't be easily deleted. I could also imagine that some users who think that SO is too negative and there are too many downvotes that they tend to upvote randomly everything and sometimes also upvote such posts.

Comment: Can we also throw in qualifiers such as outstanding "unclear" or "too broad" close votes on a question independent of its total positive score?  I encountered this the other day and I'd like to know those stats, too.

Comment: There are also well meaning users who don't know what is expected of questions on Stack Overflow and think that behind all of the bad formatting and un-clarity there is a good question. These people don't know that we should be voting on the questions in their current state, instead of an unclear possible future state.

Comment: @Makoto I agree with the "unclear" part, but "too broad" can also apply to questions that are merely complex but do show an abundance of research. [Prime example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32987103).

Comment: @Siguza:  Note that I did say *outstanding*.  That question doesn't have any outstanding flags on it.

Comment: There are many other reasons too, but in addition, certain areas of the world tend to exhibit "voting ring" style behaviors as well.

Comment: Steve does upvote those. Screw you Steve.

Comment: Is it bad to assume that answers got upvoted because [Tim lost his keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/318307)?

Comment: *I thought they were a cyber-myth:)* @ThingyWotsit Like the users who refuse to down vote on moral grounds, I have seen a few comments on Meta where users have said that they either: 1) up vote any answer where it looks like the user tried 2) up vote a question they agree is bad but think the score is "too low". In fact there are a few questions about voting to "fix" a post's score.

Comment: I wouldn't be so quick to dismiss sock puppetry or other forms of voting fraud. A question that has no punctuation whatsoever, yet has been upvoted at least twice, is a very strong signal to me that something is afoot. I'd say that most of the time I see this, I can track down either a question-banned main account that's trying to prop up a new one or a ring of coworkers coordinating votes. We know that some companies teach their employees to do this. When I see a comment like Hovercraft's, I tend to look a little closer at the question and asker.

Comment: "People are stupid enough to actually find such questions good" Well, not stupid, but consider this: the people who upvote such questions are more likely than not the kind of people who would post questions of similar quality of their own. In other words, the reason they find such questions good is simply that their standards are just that low (or nonexistent).

Comment: It could be that the person who up-voted the question saw something there that wasn't immediately obvious. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43390869/revisions) as initially posted had spelling and grammar mistakes and on the surface seemed to be a bad question, but someone was able to edit it into a good question and provide an insightful answer.

Comment: I randomly up and downvote questions when I'm bored.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256357/drive-by-upvotes?rq=1#comment29496_256357

Comment: "People are stupid enough to actually find such questions good" - statements like this are detrimental to open discussions. A person who's actually voting for such questions, or finds value where others don't, would not admit it after being called "stupid".

Comment: **Possible improvement:** only show this data for "new" upvotes (e.g. cast in the last 1 or 3 months). This is an easy way to roughly address the fact that the reputation at the time of voting is a lot more significant than the current reputation (which would be an even better signal if that data's available).

Comment: This might be somewhat *interesting*, but are we expecting any *actionable* feedback from this data? If yes, will [so] implement it? I assume "no" on both counts - I've generally just accepted the barrier of entry here is way too low (i.t.o both asking and voting) and plenty of people care more about being nice than helping create a high-quality site.

Comment: I have seen many question that were up-voted shortly after being posted, while being poor questions. I am quite convinced such cases are mostly up-votes from co-workers. When the question receives only one or two such votes, I do not think we can do much about it. That does not look enough to warrant an action such as a ban. And it may also be up-votes from unrelated people believing they have the same trouble and hoping an answer.

Comment: Votes from deleted accounts are normally removed, so there won't be any stats on *those*. There are exceptions, but those are rare (a manual choice by the CMs to retain votes for highly accounts that have been highly active and cast a lot of votes).

Comment: I have reservations about your criteria. Less than 5 upvotes = a "terrible" question? What about the hundreds of questions with less than 5 upvotes because they address problems that aren't commonly encountered or searched? Many times I've found an excellent question with many good answers that had less than 5 upvotes. A better criteria would take into account the number of commas and periods (besides ellipses), the length of the question and the presence of a jsfiddle link. And it would still be a fairly poor criteria.

Comment: Also, I feel motivated to upvote questions because of badges, and although I don't upvote terrible ones, I will often upvote a question with subpar grammar or effort because it addresses the problem I'm solving and is *good enough*. I'm not stingy with my upvotes; they're not a scarce resource.

Comment: @IsaacLyman No, I said "less than 5 upvotes _in addition to_ the rest". My intention is merely to exclude controversial questions. Clarified that in my post.

Comment: @Siguza Okay, that makes sense. Thanks for clarifying; I took the criteria to be "either-or."

Comment: I am personally _very_ convinced by your combined reasons "Sock puppetry" + "attempt at encouragement" in the case of a question actually being a homework team assignment, as your example likely is => _voting ring, co-workers_… I also cannot resist being convinced by the first one "actually find such questions good", remembering the [Dunning–Kruger effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect); I am sure we all know some people who value their alike _more_ than the actual competent ones… => _low standards_, etc.

Comment: @Kobi: I feel that "stupid" is not referring to the level of programming expertise, but the complete unawareness that allowing these questions to multiply ruins the utility of the site for *everyone*.  Unawareness that it is actually in the best interests of novices to have a well-curated set of answers to well-written novice questions, rather than a mechanical Turk that accepts any mumbled query thrown at the wall.

Comment: As long as we're guessing here in the comments, there may be the occasional voter who sees a lazy, poorly formatted question and doesn't rate it for effort, style or adherence to the site's customs and norms, but on the basis of "I'd sure like to know the answer to that". Or even, "huh, I've been using X for years and I never thought to ask that". I can guarantee it happens, because I occasionally do this myself. Inquisitive beginners will probably be curious about some pretty basic stuff, that's how it is.

Comment: @IsaacLyman Have you considered fixing the grammar, *then* upvoting?  Either you can edit without approval, or you will get a message when it is approved.

Comment: @pnuts, that is likely the answer's poster who upvotes. After all, why having put effort into answering if the question was too bad for having an upvote?

Comment: People trying to do their [Civic Duty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty) or simply just [Vox Populi](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1108/vox-populi), or people rushing through the first posts queue?

Comment: I always figured it was from fellow students (a lot of the bad questions with upvotes that I've seen seem to be homework-related).  Somebody posts a question and talks his friend/classmate/dormmate into upvoting it right away--perhaps thinking it will draw attention to the question and get help quicker.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44229883/how-to-implement-family-tree-in-ios) has 2 upvotes! Why?!

Comment: I would recommend clarifying this with some links (and screenshots, please, since they're probably going to be deleted) for the questions you're thinking of.

Comment: @Bart screw you too. :)

Comment: @Paulw11 And two favourites; definitely suspicious

Comment: @alexis I can tell you from experience that users like that do exist - I was one of them. When I first stumbled across Stack Exchange, I was upvote-crazy, primarily because I was finding such interesting content (both questions and answers). I may be atypical, but I used to spend hours reading through top-voted questions in the technologies I was learning, and hit the vote cap on more than one occasion. I would not be surprised if others had/have the same behavior!

Comment: Those can be **Vox Populi** or **Suffrage** badge hunters.

Comment: "People are stupid enough to actually find such questions good"[sic].  The people who upvote it, are more likely the people who are smart enough to read the content and vote on that vs. voting on the questions "looks".  Voting on "looks" seems much more "shallow" and perhaps indicates a lack of critical reading skills or the tendency to respond to messages with more than  140 characters with "TLDR".

Comment: Some just read the title and upvote,Some are people don't have idea of the programming language and assume that it shows effort,some are of the newcomers who are new to SO rules,some help vampires who also faced a similar problem and it goes on...

Comment: I sometimes hesitate then end up voting up a "bad" question, only because it is actually a good question (only written badly) and leads to very useful answer(s)

Comment: @IsaacLyman [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540270/simple-server-client-chat)'s a *gimme teh codez* question with two upvotes featuring link-only answers with 3 and 4 upvotes. I bet you can find one with 5 if you search hard enough.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what was the question? It's deleted.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice, I still have this behavior (including the part about reading to educate myself :-)). Maybe I was being too subtle, but it's not necessarily "stupid" to appreciate such questions. If a question teaches me something I wanted to know, why shouldn't it be upvoted? Improving the quality of the questions is not everyone's top concern (well, maybe here on meta :-)).

Comment: @DavidConrad http://imgur.com/a/8UQPS

Comment: Sympathy upvotes from people with similar issues/similar quality standards (or lack thereof) and people who ask their friends/coworkers to upvote their question probably make up the lion's share of these.

Comment: @ivarni thanks for posting the screenshot. I agree that's pretty much blatantly a "gimme code" question. It deserved a close but "too broad" barely fits. I'm not sure what a better close reason would be though. Taking a wild guess as to a possible (legit) reason for an upvote is (it wasn't me), maybe the upvoter read the question as "How do I generate a [random number between 1 and 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/how-do-i-generate-random-integers-within-a-specific-range-in-java) repeatedly and keep a running total in Java"; which might be a bit better but it's nearly a dupe...

Comment: ... also for what it's worth even edited to be "How do I generate a random number between 1 and 3 repeatedly and keep a running total in Java" IMO there's not enough value added to have a question that's basically "How do I generate random numbers" plus "How do I add and store integers". Is it worth having some kind of dedicated close reason for "this question isn't a duplicate but you should have been able to figure it out based on these two questions"?

Comment: I am skeptical that there is in fact a single significant reason. The Stack Overflow model provides a variety of explicit and implicit incentives for voting, both up and down, and unjustified up-votes may be caused by a variety of these different reasons. I will say, as frustrating as I find up-votes on really bad questions (i.e. as HFOL says, "who would be so dumb as to up-vote this?"), in the long run I doubt it matters much. If the question is really so bad that an up-vote is obviously wrong, the question will eventually die from down- and close-votes, and the up-votes won't matter.

Comment: I'm also pretty certain that some users who post an answer will also upvote a question, either to encourage the asker to vote themselves or counter a downvote someone else has given. There is a fairly large incentive as an answerer to do this.

Comment: Terrible people do. That's who!

Comment: @Aximili in that case please also [use your editing privilege to help others see the same good question that you do](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261574/603977).

Comment: Who upvoted this question?

Comment: @animuson _please_ don't perpetuate this "pity" or "sympathy" upvote myth. Data does not support it.. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93356/is-there-an-actual-pity-or-sympathy-upvote-problem

Comment: There has been one major change over the last 20 years: KIDS ON THE INTERNET does that answer it for you?

Answer (score 48):

You're dismissing sock puppetry too easily here. I have spotted several accounts on SO which are certainly upvoted by sock puppets. Those may be hard to spot, but once you find them, those accounts indeed look irregular:

- They have asked many crappy questions, often upvoted to match for the downvotes. This way those questions don't catch the eye, yet the account gets +8 per up/down vote pair. Reporting those to the moderators usually yields nothing, unless they have hundreds of questions like that.
- They often have answers to duplicate questions which are copied from answers of the original question (or some other source), plus a meaningless intro like "Excellent question!" or "I think you should try this". Those are often upvoted despite comments reporting the source of the original answer. Reporting these to the moderators typically results in the answer being removed, but nothing happens to the account unless there are tens of answers like that.

I hope this doesn't sound like rant against the moderators (because it isn't, I'm against the "let God sort them out" approach myself). I'm just pointing out that there's indeed a lot of irregular voting going on on SO, and fighting against it is pretty much a thankless full-time job which nobody has the time for. Upvoted terrible questions you see are one of the by-products.

Comment: A vote-bot that attempts to look more organic by pseudo-randomly upvoting (and sometimes downvoting) completely unrelated stuff is also something I suspect sometimes.

Comment: Can you post some screenshots of questions where this happened?

Comment: What you're suggesting is that this is almost entirely done by sock puppets.  *Perhaps*, but those accounts are routinely destroyed, so the votes wouldn't matter over time.  Gut feeling is that we're keen on finding patterns related to non-sock accounts which just do this sort of thing.

Comment: Alternative gut feeling: there are real users who are dumb as socks. @makoto

Comment: @jrh [Here you go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27118811/4350586). Note that while my flag on this one was found "helpful", no action was taken despite the fact that the user has several "answers" like this one. This kind of discouraged me from further sock hunting.

Comment: @Makoto BTW, my comment above is also relevant to you. Perhaps such accounts are routinely destroyed, but they are also routinely created and many seep through.

Comment: @CodyGray If that is the case, I blame the association bonus and the HNQ list.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev - Look at that user's [reputation history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4226000/muhammad-wasim?tab=reputation), particularly January 30, 2016 and October 18, 2015. Just because a user isn't destroyed or suspended doesn't mean that we didn't do anything. I handled that flag, and can say that all anomalous voting was corrected there soon after you flagged it. I wouldn't let this discourage you from pointing out others, because that flag was helpful in cleaning up the votes on dozens of questions.

Comment: @BradLarson Thanks for clearing that up, I didn't realize the amount of work you guys have done behind the scenes. I must have just looked at one of the posts, seen that it's still upvoted and assumed nothing was done. I'll be sure to check the rep history next time.

Comment: @Makoto - In terms of sheer numbers of questions impacted, I'd say voting rings have a much larger role than sock puppets. People significantly underestimate how many people are encouraged or ordered to vote for their bosses or coworkers at many companies. True sock puppets are easy to deal with, voting rings can be a lot trickier to judge and handle, and they can impact dozens or hundreds of posts. Unfortunately, they often require manual intervention at the SE level to invalidate votes going the various ways, and the time of SE employees is limited.

Comment: @BradLarson Do you have a threshold value for statistics like "user A received X% of their upvotes from user B"? IMO when the amount of received votes becomes significant (more than 50-100), such voting rings should become visible in the stats.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev - Yes, we have something like that, but there are tricky questions about whether that's [a natural occurrence due to overlap in tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314096/19679), the human tendency to vote for people they know, or if there's more directed coordination on the votes. Identification is only half of the problem, because most of the time these votes need to be manually invalidated by SE staff (moderators can't do this), and their time is extremely limited. This causes us to focus on the worst, most publicly visible cases first.

Comment: @BradLarson:  Perhaps you're right; that's one piece of SO that I will willingly confess naivete to, not just because it's harder for the average person to see, but because it's easy for those things to fall into typical patterns of assumptions.  Perhaps some insights into how voting rings are dealt with would be beneficial?  Nothing too in-depth to reveal how you got to them, that is.

Answer (score 17):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but a lot of people nearly only upvote content. Feel free to play with this and change the thresholds:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/682614/upvotes-as-more-than-n-of-votes?PERCENTUPVOTES=90&MINVOTES=1000

As far as I can tell, there's no way to tell whether those votes are on questions or answers from the data explorer (though you can click on profiles to see).

What it really means is many people have a tendency to upvote, not downvote. Many of the top users on that list have *surely* seen tons of bad content worth downvoting...

Comment: 70000 upvotes and no downvotes! :O, about 2/3rds of my votes are downvotes

Comment: I'm at 53% upvotes to 47% downvotes, and I'm not downvoting nearly as much as I technically should (taking the rules seriously)

Comment: It would be interesting to see if there is a correlation between high up/downvote ratio and the number of answers on ultimately closed questions. Seems to me if a user is not willing to downvote, they may be unwilling to VtC or otherwise moderate bad questions, opting instead to answer them. I don't have the SQL fu to answer that one though.

Comment: Wow, now the top is ~115 *thousand* upvotes vs 0 downvotes.... some 27 per day, everyday, for the last 11+ years. Where are they finding all this treasure? Must be a different website or something...

Comment: I tried it again 6 years later, and played around a bit. The results are truly stunning. Among the ~36k users who have cast a thousand votes or more, the **median** percentage of upvotes is **98.2%**.

Comment: Curiously, when I sort the users with 1k+ votes and look for the ones with the highest downvote ratios, I just keep seeing username after username of all the people I respect highly for having a superior understanding of Stack Overflow policy, the people who truly Get It and who have been working tirelessly to fix this garbage fire. (It's more stunning if I sort by absolute number of downvotes.)

Comment: On the other hand, the *overall* percentage of upvotes in this group is only about 81.4% (using a totally different query - and compared to 88.2% overall, 88.0% for people who actually have downvote privileges). So we have some "elite" crew putting in overtime to correct the overall ratio, I guess, but they aren't very successful. Interestingly, people at 1 reputation with 1000+ votes, vote only 30.7% positive - I guess this is largely suspended users who got suspended for going on massive downvoting sprees? Except, there are daily limits...

Answer (score -23):

This is old but still relevant, children are now a thing online more and more every day. You have to consider that there *might* be a 4-year-old clicking that like button.

"But the accounts require verification, etc.."  How many parents do you suppose let their kids use their devices. Many of which are logged in when they do so, so if anyone using that device just clicks on the "sign up with Google" button, and passwords are auto-filled, you can easily (even a 4-year-old) sign up and log in. Often this is the case. (And let’s be clear, if *you* don't let your kids do this, that doesn't mean the whole world doesn't—far too many people think they are the same as everyone else).

Parents don't usually check to make sure their kids are upvoting answers properly. They are more concerned with them going to adult sites. As long as they aren't, anything else is fine.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not appealing to kids. It looks boring, there's lots of boring text... This answer is an extreme stretch. I mean, kids that know how to hit an upvote button also know how to open more interesting sites / apps.

Comment: That is an [interesting theory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UuCqeg4zV_o&list=PLSoD2CcPrumFJREVL6RmMnZP5U7sGYYi2&t=51s), but how would they find Stack Overflow in the first place?

Comment: Stack Overflow does not allow "children" to be part of this community.

Comment: This is surely not the reason for *all* upvotes on terrible questions, but surely that has happened before, such accidents aren't that uncommon.

Comment: This is really irrelevant. You might as well point out that *some* upvotes might come from a cat walking across the keyboard. The number of upvotes coming from young children spamming random inputs into the Internet is vanishingly small. The question is not about trying to hunt down *all remotely possible sources of upvotes*, just the probable and (ideally) statistically significant ones.

Comment: Let's not forget that you also do need the 15 rep to actually have your upvote matter.